# Probability that 5/9 players flop a heart flush in Texas Holdem

Tags: probability, poker

need some help with this one.

Want to know the probability of 5 players in a 9 player game, all get dealt 2 hearts, and then the flop comes 3 more hearts.

Cheers for all the answers. Makes a lot of sense now.

I understand that there are 9c5 ways of arranging the 2card heart players out of 9. I am curious as to why it is this simple, and doesn't take into account the probability that the remaining hearts don't get drawn by the other players, or in the burn pile before the flop.

If there is any confusion. 9 Players in the game, 18 cards get dealt left to right 1 at a time to all players. 1 card is then burnt. 3 cards are then dealt (the flop) this is where the question ends.

Comment: I think i'm just confusing myself at this point. 9c5 ways of arranging the players. As soon as the first 5 hearts are dealt to players,  that order of players would effective the probability. If players 1,2,3,4,5 get the hearts on the first 5 cards, then players 6,7,8,9 need to not draw a heart, which is easy enough to work out, but my confusion lies with not knowing what order the first 5 hearts come out.

After the cards are dealt, probability that burn card is not a heart, 29/34, next 3 cards being hearts are 3/33 x 2/32 1/31

Comment: I would look at this differently: $23$ cards are drawn, $13$ of them have to be hearts. That's one probability you can calculate. Then you have to distribute them correctly (three among the flop, the rest to the players so that no player recieves only one), which is a separate probability to calculate. Then you multiply the two together.

Comment: Isn't it 22 cards drawn? 18 + 1 + 3? So 22 cards come out of the deck, 13 of them have to be hearts. So 22c13 ways of arranging the cards?

Comment: $9$ hands are $18$ cards, and then $5$ cards are shown face up (with appropriate betting rounds between). At least that's the hold'em rules I'm used to. Not that it matters much to the approach I've outlined.

Comment: What about the burn cards too though? And the last 3 hearts have to be the first 3 on the flop

Comment: The burn cars are irrelevant; no one gets any information about them, so they might just as well be left in the deck (when drawing cars from a shuffled deck, there is no difference between drawing the first card, the second, the middle or the bottom card; they are the same). But I am somewhat unfamiliar with the jargon, so if flop is the first three cards, rather than the full five, then we arrive at $21$ cards drawn.

Comment: Are we given that five players get two hearts each and computing the chance that three of the common cards are hearts, or are we computing the overall chance that the hearts are distributed that way?

Comment: Just want to know the probability that 5 players all get dealt 2 hearts each, the other 4 players can get dealt whatever. And then the first 3 cards that get dealt on the flop are the remaining 3 hearts

Comment: Someone should get BruceET to write a simulation for this...

Comment: But I think both answers are correct: There are $\binom{52}{13}$ ways to arrange $13$ hearts (treated as indistinguishable) in the deck, and only $\binom{9}{5}$ ways to arrange them so as to satisfy the conditions.  That the other four players don't get the hearts is implicit in the fact that the $\binom{9}{5}$ isn't multiplied by anything: Once you've selected which five players get the two hearts, there's only one way to arrange the remaining three hearts to satisfy the conditions; they have to go in the flop.  In other words, you can think of the $\binom{9}{5}$ as $\binom{9}{5} \times 1$.

Answer (score 1):

You use the fact that the order in which cards are dealt does not matter (and also that the burn card doesn't matter).

You can find the probability that $5$ select players get the hearts, by simply assuming that you turn the flop and deal these players first. There's $13!$ ways the first $13$ cards will give only hearts out of a total of $52!/39!$ ways of doing that. That is probability of $13!39!/52!$

Now there are $9!/5!4!$ ways of choosing the players to get the hearts and all these are complementary events of propability of $13!39!/52!$. Consequently the probability is:

$${13!39!9!\over5!4!52!} = {9\over 45358111400}$$

One way to realize the ordering the dealing is done doesn't matter is to see that we're basically counting the number of arrangements (shufflings) of the deck that has hearts in prescribed positions. In my reasoning we're interested in those that has hearts at the first $13$ positions, but in fact these are exactly as many as those that has hearts in any select $13$ positions.

We see this since we can craft a way $\Pi$ to rearrange the deck so that the cards at the select $13$ position are placed on the top (one should note that after constructing that rearrangement we can also create a scheme that will restore the order to the oringinal).

The important thing here is that if we have an enumeration $S_j$ of all possible shufflings of the deck then $\Pi S_j$ will also enumerate all shufflings. But if $Sj$ has hearts on the select positions $\Pi S_j$ will have it on the first $13$ positions.

This means that if we list all shufflings $S_j$ along the shufflings $\Pi S_j$ and count the number of shufflings in the $S_j$ column with hearts on select positions and $\Pi S_j$ with hearts at the first positions we see that we will count one on both sides simultaneously and therefore reach the exact same result.

Comment: Thankyou for your reply. Any chance you could explain to me why we can just assume 'turn the flop and deal these players first'. Wouldn't the probability be effected by the order in which those cards are dealt. When dealing the cards out, 10 non heart cards will be dealt before the flop comes out. Don't we have to take into account the chance that players who have been dealt 1 heart can also be dealt a non heart on the 2nd, and players who were not dealt a heart could be dealt a heart on card 2. I am just confused because of the physical way in which these cards would be dealt out.

Comment: @fresh143:  once you specify the positions in the deck that have to be hearts, you can just reorder the deck and dealing order to deal those first.

Comment: @fresh143 I've tried to explain it in plain english. Basically you consider the set of permutations (of the deck) that will have hearts on select positions and the set of permutaitions that have hearts on the first positions and form a bijection between these sets which therefore must have equal number of elements.

Comment: I didn't see your edit. Thanks

Comment: @fresh143 Have you refreshed the page?

Answer (score 0):

There are ${9 \choose 5}=126$ ways to pick the players who get the hearts.  The chance of each of those coupled with the flop all being hearts is the chance you draw the $13$ hearts first out of a deck, which is the inverse of ${52 \choose 13}$ so the overall probability is $$\frac{126}{52 \choose 13}=\frac 9{45358111400}\approx 2 \cdot 10^{-10}$$

Comment: Doesn't 9C5 just show how many ways 5 players can be picked from 9. The cards are dealt 1through 9 twice, not 2 at a time, not sure if it effects it. How can we say that once 1 heart comes out, a second will come out, without being given to another player

Comment: Once you pick the five players you have defined ten slots in the deck that must contain hearts.  Picking the three common cards gets the other three.  The point is then what fraction of the permutations of the deck have hearts in exactly those thirteen positions.

Comment: 'The point is then what fraction of the permutations of the deck have hearts in exactly those thirteen positions' I think I understand the rest, but at most, there will be 22 cards drawn. How does this come into effect. The 126 permutations of players, means that the 13 hearts have to be in these 22 cards, in ways which will give 2 to each of the 5. Haha thankyou for your reply but I am still confused

Comment: and (53)=10(53)=10 ways to choose the common cards that are hearts. This means how many ways the 5 communal cards can have 3 hearts. I want to know the P of the first 3 cards to be hearts, not 3/5

Comment: I missed that the flop has to be hearts, not three of the five communal cards.  I will update.  It just divides the chance by $10$